# the link to css file does not work, a have check everything, still does not work, anybody answer me, what is wrong?

Tags: java, html, css, model-view-controller

html file cannot see css file

in my previous project the same link to css file worked[enter image description here](https://i.stac##

1.

---

### **[image: Heading]**

##k.imgur.com/u6L9P.png)

Comment: you gave a screenshot of the link that works but no screenshot for the link that doesn't work.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the page makes a request for the CSS file, what is the URL of that request?  Does it match what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Please include actual code and not screenshots of code.  Also please actually include your code that does not work so people can help you with it.

Comment: Things that you need to know to solve your problem. (1) The URL of the HTML document that your server is generating from your template. (2) The absolute URL that the relative URL in your `<link>` resolves to. (3) How the HTTP server you are using generates static URLs for static files. (4) Where on your file system you should put static files for *3* to work.

Comment: it is first time i am publishing the question here, i am sorry for non-informativeness

Comment: Not at all - that is why WE are here - to answer questions of every level. Remember that we once were where you are now, so we are happy to lend a helping hand. Ask away! But do NOT become discouraged if some people are rude. Sometimes even people with very high rep scores are unkind. Just keep asking!

Comment: i posted the screenshot of the code that does not work, i highlighted the link to css url and there is no response from browser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The webserver will look for your CSS file starting from the location of your index file. ***Important: See Quentin's note under your question for important information when you are using templates and frameworks. This sentence only applies to traditional HTML construction - but it also applies once your project has been generated and uploaded to the web server.***

According to that code, the file `style.css` should be in the same folder as the index file, and spelled exactly as specified. Capitalization matters: Style.css is not style.css.

Did you move the style.css file into a subfolder? Is the capitalization different?

Comment: "The webserver will look for your CSS file starting from the location of your index file." — Since the template is in a directory called "templates" and there is a folder named "static" in the image, that statement is probably incorrect for this web server.

Comment: my html file and css fila are in the same directory

Comment: capitalization matters

Comment: checked everything, tried some ways to fix problem, still html file does not see css file, there is no bug appears, browser show page without css, anybody help, show the place where the the mistake is, it spent 4 fours to fix this bug

Comment: Use DevTools. On the page created by your HTML, press F12 (or Right-Click and choose Inspect). This shows the HTML that created the page. Go up to the **head** element and locate the style tag. What does the tag say? Now, create a new tab and try the URL: `https://yourdomain.com/path-to-your-style.css` - or, on localhost: `http://localhost/templates/style.css`. THEN, experiment with that URL until you actually open the style.css and see the text. Update your question and post a screenshot of what you see in DevTools for the style tag.

Comment: What happens if you change the `<link>` for your stylesheet to just `style.css` ?  Also, because you had a capitalization issue earlier, try renaming your stylesheet just to `bob.css`. The trick is to be able to open your stylesheet from the browser address bar - that will help you discover the relationship between the index file and the style.css file. Are they in the same folder? If so, you should be able to open `http://domain_or_127.0.0.1/style.css`